# Cannot use React.lazy with Material UI icons

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

as I have quite a lot of icons in many places in my app, I want to use code splitting for them.

I have created helper component to do that:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent, Suspense } from 'react';

interface LazyMuiIconProps {
  name: string;
}

export const LazyMuiIcon: FunctionComponent<LazyMuiIconProps> = ({ name }) => {
  console.log(name);
  const IconElement = React.lazy(() => import(`@material-ui/icons/${name}`));
  // const IconElement = React.lazy(() => import(`@material-ui/icons/Home`));
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <IconElement />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

When I use commented line with fixed name to `Home` it works and it lazy loads the Home icon, however as soon as I change it to the line above, webpack crashes during compilation with low level error:

> 69% building 15623/15657 modules 34 active
>   ...terial-ui/icons/AccessibleOutlined.d.ts <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [30:0x33f4320]    77272 ms: Scavenge 1142.0 (1422.8) -> 1141.5
>   (1423.3) MB, 1.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.300, current mu = 0.342)
>   allocation failure  [30:0x33f4320]    77275 ms: Scavenge 1142.3
>   (1423.3) -> 1141.7 (1423.8) MB, 1.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.300,
>   current mu = 0.342) allocation failure  [30:0x33f4320]    77278 ms:
>   Scavenge 1142.4 (1423.8) -> 1141.9 (1424.3) MB, 1.5 / 0.0 ms  (average
>   mu = 0.300, current mu = 0.342) allocation failure
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x16ac4804fb5d] Security context: 0x02fea7a9d921 <JSObject>
> 1: add [0x2fea7a906c9](this=0x10fbf120c2e1 <Set map = 0x3f914303d81>,0x1a97709947e1 <DependenciesBlock map =
> ```
>
> 0x1c000787d3b1>)
>       2: new Set(aka Set) [0x2fea7a90391](this=0x056d59402691 ,0x33036eb7fbe1 )
>       3: ConstructFrame [pc: 0x16ac48009e66]
>       4: StubFrame [pc: 0x16ac480f932c]
>       5: processDependenciesBlocksForC...
>                                                                    70% chunk graphFATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit
>   Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 0x948d20
>   node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: 0x9499bc
>   node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  3:
>   0xb1160e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  4: 0xb11844
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  5: 0xf0def2 
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  6: 0xf0dff8
>   v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  7: 0xf1a718
>   v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
>   v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]  8: 0xf1b22b
>   v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
>   v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  9: 0xf1df61
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 10: 0xee7e96
>   v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray(int,
>   v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node] 11: 0xee885a
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex,
>   int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 12: 0xee8900
>   v8::internal::Handle
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithMap(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex,
>   int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node] 13: 0x108e547
>   v8::internal::OrderedHashTable::Allocate(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 14: 0x1091ab1
>   v8::internal::OrderedHashTable::Rehash(v8::internal::Isolate*,
>   v8::internal::Handle, int)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 15: 0x109202b
>   v8::internal::OrderedHashTable::EnsureGrowable(v8::internal::Isolate*,
>   v8::internal::Handle)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 16: 0x117ee2c v8::internal::Runtime_SetGrow(int,
>   v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>   17: 0x16ac4804fb5d  Aborted (core dumped)

My Babel plugins:

```
plugins: [
                // plugin-proposal-decorators is only needed if you're using experimental decorators in TypeScript
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
                'react-hot-loader/babel',
```

From what I see it is trying to load all icons, not just one (I reduced the used instance to one to find the solution easier) and then it crashes.

**UPDATE**

Exactly the same happens if I try to use `react-loadable`...

```js
return Loadable({
    loader: () => import(`@material-ui/icons/${props.name}`),
    loading: () => <span>icon</span>
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Webpack, the problem is if you want to dynamic load a file, in this case the icon, webpack by default generate a chunk for that module. If you are using Webpack 4 or later, you can use `webpackMode: eager` to solve this problem. So, in this case, the import will look something like this :

```
const IconElement = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */`@material-ui/icons/${name}`));
```

This will basically force Webpack to include the chunk into your bundle ( reducing the number of http requests )  - which I think renders the whole point of using Lazy / Suspense useless but this [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5940) is similar to your problem and indicates that it is not worth loading each icon separately, .i.e, you should rather import the `@material-ui/icons` package and use the icons which you need.

**UPDATE ( because of update in question with reference to `react-loader` ) :**

While using `react-loader` you also need to specify the extension of the file. I had faced this issue once and solved it by importing with extension for the file specified. In this case :

```
return Loadable({
    loader: () => import(`@material-ui/icons/${props.name}.ts`),
    loading: () => <span>icon</span>
  });
```

But I am not sure if it will still work, as I already suggested in my answer regarding Webpack and lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you! I made it with static import as it makes sense that it would be to many requests but I will know it for any future reuse.