# How to import Material UI Icons with React.lazy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, material-ui, codesandbox

I have created a component once to load Material UI Icons dynamically inside of the component. The icon name comes from component props.

You can see the source here => https://codesandbox.io/s/react-materialicon-component-olntq?file=/src/MaterialIcon.js

It was working very well. I just found out it doesn't anymore.

This is how the component looks like. Also, I recommend have a look at the Codesandbox link I shared above.

[image]

Comment: Although it's not recommended to use code splitting to generate this many chunks, as you can see here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5940#issuecomment-443503347, you should read this answer and check if the use of "webpack:eager" is solving your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/54838920/5810646

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. Weird but the same import method doesn't work on the root level too. It looks like default export doesn't work.

Comment: @cooskun Did you find out what is the problem?

Comment: @JV I couldn't figure out. The problem is been fixed for no reason. It might be a Codesandbox issue.